# Do a lot of sequences in mariadb have an impact on performance?

Tags: mariadb

We heavily use mariadb sequences for key based naming series generation. We eventually realised that we have hit 5,000+ sequences and many more (40k-50K) to come.

Till now we do not see any major impact on performance, however, knowing that every sequence internally creates a table, will this cause any major impact in future?

We use `desc <table>` command a lot which scans information_schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have specifics, but...

- The OS probably has troubles with 50K tables -- each table is one or more file in the oS.
- `AUTO_INCREMENT` is extremely well optimized; use that whenever practical.
- Consider MariaDB's third sequencing object:  pseudo tables like `seq_1_to_10`, which probably takes very little overhead.

I find that `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is more descriptive than `desc`.  But why do you need it "a lot"?  Once an hour is "rather often" for that query.  (I am looking at the `STATUS` value `Com_create_table`; I suspect `DESCRIBE` increments that.)

Comment: Thanks. We have been using desc to get field metadata of tables, as we use a framework which "guesses" the schema.